# Получение большого количества ссылок Selenium с последующим внесением их в массив

Tags: python, selenium

```
browser.get('http://forum.revent-rp.ru/') # Адресс форума

onlineusers = 79
users = []
link = browser.find_element_by_class_name('name')
link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')


for i in range(onlineusers):
    users.append(link.text)
```

На форуме внизу есть список пользователей онлайн. Мне нужно получить ссылки на их аккаунты и внести их в массив. Но как сделать так, чтобы получить много ссылок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парсер на Selenium. Но как говорил @hedgehogues, лучше с ним не парсить так как слишком медленный, а смотреть в сторону Beautiful Soup или вообще lxml.

C помощью Selenium парсят только в том случае, если страница генерируется с помощью Javascript

```
users = []
ff = "../../install/chromedriver" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff)
driver.get('http://forum.revent-rp.ru/') # Адрес форума


block_users = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#board_statistics>p:not([class])')
users_a = block_users.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
for user_a in users_a:
    users.append(user_a.get_attribute('href'))


print(users)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Хорошо, а можете показать как сделать не на Selenium?

Comment: Добавьте этому ответу репутацию, а я пока напишу на lxml

Comment: не могли бы вы вот тут помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878715/Парсинг-ссылок-селениум

Answer (score 3):

На lxml + request:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
users = []
url = 'http://forum.revent-rp.ru/' # Адрес форума

def get_html(request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = get_html(r)
    block_users = html.cssselect('#board_statistics>p:not([class])')[0]
    users_a = block_users.cssselect('a')
    for user_a in users_a:
        users.append(user_a.get('href'))
    print(users)
```