# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import sys, os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

import time


system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

path_to_chromedriver = str(system + "\\chromedriver.exe")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

browser.get("https://pass.rzd.ru/tickets/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=704&refererPageId=4065&layer_name=e3-route&tfl=3&st0=КАЗАНЬ+(ВСЕ+ВОКЗАЛЫ)&code0=2060615&dt0=12.01.2019&st1=МОСКВА+КАЗАНСКАЯ+(КАЗАНСКИЙ+ВОКЗАЛ)&code1=2000003&checkSeats=0")

findtrain = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("route-item")

findnameoftrain = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("route-trnum")


time.sleep(5)

findbuttoncupe = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div").click()

time.sleep(5)

findbuttonwagon = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[11]/div/div[1]/a").click()

time.sleep(2)

find98 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[11]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/svg/g[3]/g[10]").click()

# time.sleep(2)
#
# find100 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("").click()


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Описание программы:

1. Программа должна найти поезд №023Г
2. Программа должна зайти в "купе"
3. Программа должна зайти в Вагон №10
4. Программа должна выбрать Места №98,100

Но вылетает ошибка после того, как я по Xpath пытаюсь найти 98 место и кликнуть на него.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="Page0"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[11]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/svg/g[3]/g[10]"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Comment: При редактировании вопроса, не забывайте редактировать все места где встречается ваша корректировка. Сейчас получается, что XPath у 98 места один, а ошибка выводит другой))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жмите не на `<g>`, а на входящий в него `<text>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="98"]').click()
```

И используйте по возможности короткие относительные XPath адреса, а не длинные и абсолютные)) А абсолютный, только если он вам нужен к примеру по ТЗ)))

В предложенном мною XPath можно с помощью `.format()` подставлять нужный номер места (туда где "98") и всё и дальше будет работать с нужным вам номером места))